# Which permissions do I have to allow for zfs send

Tags: permissions, freebsd, zfs

I'm trying to mirror some snapshots through zxfer as a user, on FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE, but I get stuck with

```
% zxfer -dF -I com.sun:auto-snapshot -O zxfer@zfshost -R zroot/www zroot/backup
warning: cannot send 'zroot/www/homepage@snaptest': permission denied
cannot receive: failed to read from stream
Error when zfs send/receiving.
% █
```

I did allow the `send` permission.

```
% zfs allow zroot/www/homepage
---- Permissions on zroot/www ----------------------------------------
Descendent permissions:
    user zxfer send
% id
uid=1003(zxfer) gid=1003(zxfer) groups=1003(zxfer)
% zfs send zroot/www/homepage@snaptest | wc -c
warning: cannot send 'zroot/www/homepage@snaptest': permission denied
       0
% █
```

What should I change to allow sending snapshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that your filesystem is jailed;

```
% zfs get jailed zroot/www
NAME        PROPERTY  VALUE   SOURCE
zroot/www   jailed    on      local
% █
```

Jailed filesystems can be sent according to their permissions from their jail, but outside the jail you need to be root.